# How can I give maximum CPU Utilization to this Python Process

Tags: python, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm using Spyder IDE for Data Analysis using Python. My dataset is pretty large and hence I wish to give it maximum priority. I've set the priority to realtime however it is only using 13-15% of CPU. How can I give 100% CPU usage to it? I'm using Dell Insiron 15Z ultrabook with 2 RAMs of 4 GB each.
[image]

Edit: I'm now running two scripts on two different consoles. Now the CPU usage has increased to 75%. I know this isn't the technically correct way of implementing parallelism however being a beginner in Python, I had no other option. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using any multi-threading code or other parallelization methods. Because of this, you're code is running in just one thread, which can only run on one CPU at a time. Since you have eight CPUs, this results in 1/8 of total CPU consumption.

Parallelization of code is not a trivial task, and is **highly** dependent on the type of work your program is doing.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Python Data Science. I was assuming the Anaconda IDE would take care of the parallization. Is there any easy way I can run the code parallely ?

Comment: No. Like I said, parallelization is not easy. We have no idea what kind of data analysis you're doing.

Comment: @ADITYAAWALKAR no. The only way is making your stuff run in multiple threads. It does not depend on IDE or whatsoever.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart and AlexeyVilchansky
Thank you. I'm having a for loop in my code which is running on a 2 columns of different dataframes simultaneously. I'm now running two scripts simultaneously which has increased the CPU usage. This will do for now. However for future I'm quite interested in learning parallelism in Python. Thank you :)

Comment: Do pyhton threads run in multiple CPU's, as processes do?  (Beware: I do **not** want to start a `threading` vs `multiprocessing` discussion).  You can start by looking at the documentation for both modules.  They are written to use similar, if not identical, syntax.